# How can i write with EntityFramework 5

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a sql code like this,

```
SELECT *,
(Select Count(PostID) FROM Likes Where Likes.PostID = Posts.PostID) AS Likes,
(Select Count(PostID) FROM Comments WHERE Comments.PostID = Posts.PostID) AS Comments
FROM Posts
```

But I need to write this code with EntityFramework 5. How can i write this code?
Thanks.

Comment: you didnt find this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399367(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from post in Posts
select new
{
 Post = post,
 Likes = (from like in Likes where like.PostID == post.PostID select like).Count(),
 Comments = (from comment in Comments where comment.PostID = post.PostID select post).Count()
}
```